# How can I label \rightleftarrows above and below?

Tags: math-mode, arrows, labels

How can I label `$\rightleftarrows$` above the top arrow and below the bottom arrow?

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 20):

I don't know which package defines `\rightleftarrows` but this shows how to get labels over and under one of the standard arrows.

*Edit updated to use the requested arrow*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[a \mathrel{\mathop{\rightleftarrows}^{\mathrm{over}}_{\mathrm{under}}} b\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That would be `amssymb`.

Comment: @percusse ah thanks I should have known that:-) updated answer

Comment: Is there a way to this not in amssymb? Because my work is on Wordpress, and I either use their built-in Latex or mathurl.com, neither of which support amssymb I am sure. Sorry to trouble you.

Comment: the code for the under and over label does not use any package at all, `\mathrel` and `\mathop` are primitives and `\mathrm` is standard LaTeZ (or you could use `\rm` in plain TeX) So if you can use the arrow in wordpress you should be able to use labels too. But you need something to define the arrow as it is not built in to latex.

Comment: I guess that means that Wordpress supports some sort of package because that arrow showed up.

Comment: It didn't parse, either with \mathrm or \rm.

Comment: well it is correct TeX, so you must be using a non-Tex system, which makes it bordering being off topic for this site you might do better at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In trying this, I see that it *requires* displaymath mode; using inline $...$ puts the super/subscripts after the operator. What is the reason for this; I thought displaymath mode just affected the spacing *around* the maths?

Comment: Using `\stackrel` instead does allow it to be used within inline maths, but obviously that won't allow the arrow, superscript *and* subscript (since `\stackrel` only supports a top and a bottom).

Comment: Just a side note. In order to display as expected in in-line math mode, don't forget to use `\displaystyle` before it.

Comment: @StuartRossiter Using the `\overset{}`-`\underset{}` approach explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51244/117801) might do the trick, then. It did for me for another issue, at least.

Answer (score 9):

I found a simple solution that works for me:

```
A \overset{F}{\underset{G}\rightleftarrows} X
```

Comment: Works well with the js parsers too!

Answer (score 6):

If you want an extensible arrow, you can use the trick found in Herber Voß's Mathmode (`texdoc mathmode` or http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xleftrightarrow[2][]{\ext@arrow 0099{\longleftrightarrowfill@}{#1}{#2}}
\def\longleftrightarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\leftarrow\relbar\rightarrow}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$a\xleftrightarrow[under]{over}b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added a link to texdoc.net because I didn't seem to be able to get _Mathmode_ on my MiKTeX 2.9, hope that's alright.

Comment: And congratulations to your answer No. 2000! I'll be lucky if I can keep my own rep to about a tenth of yours `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem and wasn't getting a satisfying answer. The problem is that the length of the arrows should "grow" with the text, or, at least, it should be possible to set the length manually.
Finally, I found a solution for the last option (the first one not yet solved).

```
\stackrel[\mathrm{discharge}]{\mathrm{charge}}{\overrightarrow{\underleftarrow{\hspace{2cm}}}}
```

The 2 cm can be changed as needed, the word above the arrow are "charge" and below "discharge"

Answer (score -2):

You can also consider using `\stackrel`

```
\stackrel{\rm{1:1}}{\rightarrow}
```