# Math mode - bidirectional map

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I have two categories and one functor in each direction, with relatively long names. I would like to write both functors at the same time, one over a right arrow and another one over a left arrow, so it would be like, from top to bottom, text, left arrow, right arrow and text. It would be something like the first answer to this question [How can I label \rightleftarrows above and below?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51163/how-can-i-label-rightleftarrows-above-and-below), but more like \xrightarrow would show it, with its length growing to meet the text.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170042

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the package [`extarrows`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extarrows) is what you are looking for.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\begin{document}
    \[a \xLeftrightarrow[\text{nur der Mann im Mond schaut zu}]{\text{la li lu}} b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I understood you wrong, sorry. Here is some other solution with harpoons:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \[a \xrightleftharpoons[\text{nur der Mann im Mond schaut zu}]{\text{la li lu}} b\]
    \[a \xleftrightharpoons[\text{nur der Mann im Mond schaut zu}]{\text{la li lu}} b\]
\end{document}
```

If you really want to have arrows, you will have to tweak something like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233898

Comment: That's not what I intended to do. I would like to have an arrow to the right over an arrow to the left.