# How would I specify this dually left & right arrow (categorical, two opposing functors notation)?

Tags: math-mode, arrows, mapping, arrowwithtext

[image: Forgetful functor U in one direction, free K-vector space functor V in other direction, Set to Vct_K]

This is used in *Categories for the Working Mathematician* to introduce two opposing functors U,V between the category of sets and the category of K-vector spaces, where K is a field.

Can this be done in a LaTeX code that renders on MSE?

Comment: [How can I label \rightleftarrows above and below?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51163/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: @campa, yes those answer my question